# AFNetworking 2.0 cancel specific task

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying out afnetworking 2.0 and just trying to figure out how to cancel specific tasks.
The old way would be to use something like

```
[self cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"user/receipts"]
```

but I dont see anything like this in 2.0

I created a sub class of `AFHTTPSessionManager` which gives me access to the array of pending tasks and I can cancel them directly but I dont know how to identify 1 task from another so I can cancel only specific tasks. 
Task does have an taskidentifier but this doesnt appear to be what I need.

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user/receipts"];
[self.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:[prefs valueForKey:@"uuid"] password:self.store.authToken];
[self GET:path parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
            completionBlock(responseObject);
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            errorBlock(error);
        }];
```

now if i wanted to cancel this request only how would I approach this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can store the task in a variable so you can access it later:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [self GET:path parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
            completionBlock(responseObject);
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            errorBlock(error);
        }];
```

Then simply cancel it with `[task cancel]`.

Another way would be to save the task ID of the task and later ask the URL session for its tasks and identify the task you wish to cancel:

```
// save task ID
_savedTaskID = task.taskIdentifier;

// cancel specific task
for (NSURLSessionDataTask* task in [self dataTasks]) {
    if (task.taskIdentifier == _savedTaskID) {
        [task cancel];
    }
}
```

Comment: @phix23 any idea why [task cancel] is still calling the success callback when being canceled?

Comment: I didn't thought about declaring the GET method in a NSURLSessionDataTask. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 7):

No need to save it, here is my implementation, use your subclass of  AFURLSessionManager for cancelling specific request:

```
- (void)cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithPath:(NSString *)path
{
    AFURLSessionManager * yourSessionManager = [self getSessionManager];

    [[yourSessionManager session] getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {
        [self cancelTasksInArray:dataTasks withPath:path];
        [self cancelTasksInArray:uploadTasks withPath:path];
        [self cancelTasksInArray:downloadTasks withPath:path];
    }];
}

- (void)cancelTasksInArray:(NSArray *)tasksArray withPath:(NSString *)path
{
    for (NSURLSessionTask *task in tasksArray) {
        NSRange range = [[[[task currentRequest]URL] absoluteString] rangeOfString:path];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            [task cancel];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Up-voted, but what about paths that are a substring of another request path?  i.e. "/item/1" and "/item/11" Canceling item 1 would also cancel 11. Wouldn't ```...URL] path] isEqualToString:path]``` be a better comparison?

Comment: thank you for pointing that out... I used this approach so that if a user wants to cancel all the tasks with same context it can be done easily i.e. "/school/class/students" would cancel all requests for "/school/class/students/id001" to ..id100 thus have also not put a break in the loop. Your problem can be handled by using "/item/01" and "/item/11". Anyway the comparison can be changed as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

```
NSArray *operations = [[[MyClient sharedClient] operationQueue] operations];
if(operations && operations.count > 0){
    for (NSOperation *operation in operations) {
        if([operation isKindOfClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]]){
            AFHTTPRequestOperation *httpOperation = (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation;
            NSLog(@"%@", [[httpOperation request] URL]);
            //--- if this is your request then cancel it --> [httpOperation cancel];
        }
    }
}
```

Where **MyClient** is a child of **AFHTTPClient** and the function **sharedClient** is a static function which returns a singleton instance of **MyClient**

Comment: Thank you for downgrading, but please specify the reason to share the knowledge.

Comment: Probably because your solution uses `AFHTTPClient`, which is AFN 1.x only. The question was for AFN 2.0.