# How to make an HTTP request with AFNetorking and NSURLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

I am trying to use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to make an HTTP request. I need to use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager because I want to be able to cancel all operations if necessary. I can't get this working for some reason. The completion blocks aren't called. Am I missing something?

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://twitter.com/%@", username]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:@"MyUserAgent (iPhone; iOS 7.0.2; gzip)" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [self.manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if ([html containsString:@"var h = decodeURI(l.hash.substr(1)).toLowerCase();"]) {
            completion(YES, nil);
        } else {
            completion(NO, nil);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        completion(NO, error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working code, you need to use GET or POST method there.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"email":emailfield.text};

[manager GET:@"http://example.com/api" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest method returns AFHTTPRequestOperation. You have to add it to some operation queue to start it. For example

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self.manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request .........
[[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperation:operation];
```

You can use AFHTTPSessionManager which is a little better than AFHTTPRequestOperationManager and cancel requests using method `cancel` of `NSURLSessionDataTask`. You can find some code examples here - [AFNetworking 2.0 cancel specific task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001450/afnetworking-2-0-cancel-specific-task)

Answer (score 0):

While everyone else is right -- you should be using the modern AFNetworking constructs instead of the legacy features -- there is a quick way to get done what you're looking to get done.

By the looks of it, the method `- (??? *) HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure` likely returns an `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. If I'm correct, you just need to actually start the operation. See below for your code, corrected.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://twitter.com/%@", username]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"MyUserAgent (iPhone; iOS 7.0.2; gzip)" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [self.manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if ([html containsString:@"var h = decodeURI(l.hash.substr(1)).toLowerCase();"]) {
        completion(YES, nil);
    } else {
        completion(NO, nil);
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    completion(NO, error);
}];

[op start];
```

Comment: I was trying to do it in this weird way because I'm using a shared manager for everything so that if needed, I can cancel all async operations at once which is actually a very needed functionality for my app. However, I just decided to make a second manager which has the separate header fields that I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this will work

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", nil];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```